# Could not load file or assembly 'FreeTextBox' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, filezilla

In my website, i used FreeTextBox. It working fine on localhost. But when i uploaded it on filezilla, it gives error "Could not load file or assembly 'FreeTextBox' or one of its dependencies". Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: Are you missing a dll or something like that...?

Comment: I added dll into website. As i said, it works fine on localhost. It gives error after uploading on filezilla

Answer (score 3):

I hit a similar issue after copying a solution from one location to another.

Windows had marked the DLL as from an "untrustworthy" source.

The solution for me was to right click the file and under the General Tab of the file properties click "Unblock".

This resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this line from my `licenses.licx` and it solved the problem for me.

```
FreeTextBoxControls.FreeTextBox, FreeTextBox, Version=3.3.1.12354, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5962a4e684a48b87
```